# Python tokenizer unit testing: insert one token inside a generated token list

Tags: python, unit-testing, tokenize, ply

I implement a python tokenizer to extract tokens from a text file. Tokens relate to strings which "fit to" a pattern (regular expression) i defined for every token. I use the lexer functionality from the python package ply to implement the tokenizer. After scanning the text file all found tokens are returned as generator. For unit testing i would like to insert additional tokens at defined places within the "returned token list" to verify if the tokenizer handles correctly in such a bad case situation.

How can i create a "fake" token object with ply (python module ply.lex) which i can insert into the token list.

Comment: Are you using the generated lexer's built-in iteration support? (If so, your description is incorrect, because the iterator does not scan the entire file before providing the first token.)

Comment: No. The tokenizer does an lexical analysation, does buffer all tokens (in the lexer object), but then there is some processing and looping over the lexer object (for .. in ..: yield). But you are right, it is a generator so.

Comment: Fkromer: so you are creating the list of tokens, and you want to introduce some other tokens into your list. That all sounds reasonable but i fail to see why you would then expect ply to help you with the list.

Comment: My question is how i can create a "fake" token object with ply which i can insert into the token list.

Comment: OK, I answered the question you just asked, although it was evidently not obvious to me from your actual question. I'd suggest editing the original question to add the sentence above.

Comment: the question has been improved accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily construct your own tokens, if you want to insert a token into the lex stream. (How you actually insert the token is up to you, of course.)

From the `ply` documentation:

> The tokens returned by `lexer.token()` are instances of `LexToken`. This object has attributes `tok.type`, `tok.value`, `tok.lineno`, and `tok.lexpos`.…
>
> The `tok.type` and `tok.value` attributes contain the type and value of the token itself. `tok.line` and `tok.lexpos` contain information about the location of the token. tok.lexpos is the index of the token relative to the start of the input text.

In addition, the token has a `lexer` attribute whose value is the lexer object which created the token.

Here's an example of the creation of a `LexToken` (adapted from `lex.py`), for a synthesized `error` token (`self` at this point is the lexer object):

```
tok = LexToken()
tok.value = self.lexdata[lexpos:]
tok.lineno = self.lineno
tok.type = 'error'
tok.lexer = self
tok.lexpos = lexpos
```

Comment: As the "tok.lexpos is the index of the token relative to the start of the input text" do i need to increment the attribute tok.lexpos of all following tokens? I think that would be necessary at least in the situation when i want to insert an "fake" token in between two tokens e.g. in between the two tokens of the example you referenced LexToken(NUMBER,3,2,1) and LexToken(PLUS,'+',2,2) with LexToken(.., .., .., tok.lexpos).

Comment: @fkromer: The lineno and lexpos attributes are provided by the framework but are not otherwise used by it. Typically they are used by application actions, to annotate error messages or debugging information. So it will depend on how you use the information, but normally it should not be problematic to just copy the information from the previous token.

Comment: One additional hint: Tokens are generally "commmunicated" within the application as generators. As a generator is not "subscriptable" it needs to be converted to a list with list(generator) prior to adding list items with e.g. list[:idx] + [fake_token_object] + list[idx:]